# How to get all items from the ArrayList when i looping the HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

> Im not getting the second key value from the Hashmap , Its only showning first key and its Arraylist value , how can i get all the key and Arraylist values ?

Comment: What is the error you get? Please add that to the question (see [mcve])

Comment: Errors would indicate that you are using raw `HashMap` as method parameter, not `HashMap<String, List<?>>`. However, your attached code says otherwise. So this might be compilation error somewhere else that confuses your compilator into processing this one incorrectly.

Comment: You mention 2 errors, but they cannot be thrown at the same running...

Comment: You do not need the second loop, you can just get the entry set first and you will have the array list for each key, instead of getting all keys and then doing a get again for the list. The method looks fine, can you post your stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the hash map and retrieve each key and value:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<fileModel>> entry : deviceBackUpFb.entrySet()) {

    String key = entry.getKey();
    ArrayList<fileModel> values = entry.getValue();

    for (fileModel value : values) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand your question. Try this:

```
Iterator it = deviceBackUpFb.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
}
```

And then do whatever you want with the values.

```
pair.getKey(); // String
pair.getValue(); //ArrayList<model>
```

Comment: Sorry sir . I'm getting the same result , my requirement  is i need to display each ArrayList values from the HasMap

Comment: yes and you can do that by simply iterating though `pair.getValue();`

Answer (score 1):

```
      for (Entry<String, ArrayList<fileModel>> entry : deviceBackUpFb.entrySet()){
             System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
         }
```